# Node exporter does not seems to report correct values for network bandwidth

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-node-exporter

I'm starting to monitor my home network, and I have some questions about it.
I have node exporter mipsel on my EdgeRouter, and node exporter x86_64 on my workstation.

Both are scrapped with an interval of 15s
I tried a scrape interval of 1s on the router but that was too much load for the EdgeRouter hardware.

I did a speedtest from my Linux workstation.
There are the data I can see on Grafana:

[image: speedtest in web browser]
[image: graphs on grafana]

The queries are :

For panel "Network traffic EdgeRouter":

```
sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device!~"(lo|itf0)", instance="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval]))
- sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device!~"(lo|itf0)", instance="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval]))
```

For panel "Network traffic hosts"

```
sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device!~"(lo|itf0)", instance!="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval]))
- sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device!~"(lo|itf0)", instance!="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval]))
```

Why do I have 3 different values ?

- 708 Mbps (so 88,5 MB/s) down on web based speed
- 37 MB/s on the router panel
- 13.3 MB/s on the hosts panel

I tried to remove the sum by host, and that's the same results.

---

## EDIT

I fixed the queries, now I have more consistent results, in Mbps,
I still have a question regarding the datas.

Panel: Network traffic EdgeRouter - WAN

```
sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device=~"(eth0.*)", instance="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval])) * 8 > 0
- sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"(eth0.*)", instance="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval])) * 8 < 0
```

Panel: Network traffic EdgeRouter - LAN

```
(rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device=~"(eth1\\..*)", instance="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval])) * 8 > 0
- (rate(node_network_transmit_bytes_total{device=~"(eth1\\..*)", instance="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval])) * 8 < 0
```

Panel: Network traffic hosts

```
sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device!~"(lo|itf0)", instance!="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval])) * 8 > 0
- sum by (instance) (rate(node_network_receive_bytes_total{device!~"(lo|itf0)", instance!="10.0.11.1:9100"}[$__rate_interval])) * 8 < 0
```

I changed the test to download a 5.5Gb ISO file because I don't know how speedtest by Ookla works.

The download speed was around 450 Mbps, so the max speed reported by node exporter seems right if you add the TCP overhead.

But I don't understand why the reported speed is not immediatly 450Mbps. The download through firefox was immediatly 55MB (450Mbps)

[image: results in Grafana]

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use `irate` instead of `rate`, I'm not exactly sure why though :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).